# Restart app when coming out of background

Tags: iphone, background

I've seen many news apps do this, where when you click on the app (on the iphone desktop) that has been in background mode, it starts again by showing a loading screen, etc.  It basically looks like it starts again like it was never in background mode (I think what is called "refreshing the user interface).  Does anybody know how you do this?  I assume this is call from the app's delegate applicationWillEnterForeground or applicationDidBecomeActive method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The application probably never went into the background.  Try adding this to the Info.plist file.

`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend=YES`

As a boolean value.

Comment: That's right, it's typically found in older apps that don't support multi-tasking yet