# Cannot initialise GameScene more than once using SpriteKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am trying to reset my game to the start screen every time this function is called by just creating a new scene:

```
func restart() {
    let newScene = GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    view!.presentScene(newScene)
}
```

The first time it is called, it works correctly. However, the second time it is called I get an (apparently very common) error:

> > fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don't understand why I recieve this error in this scenario.

Is there a better way to reload the entire `GameScene`? Do I need to do anything with the old discarded `GameScene` instance?

Comment: Where is the `fun restart()`?  If it is inside the GameScene, then you appear to be making more and more subviews.  Is it in the GameViewController?  I personally have a `setup()` method, and a `reset()` method, which I have add and remove nodes from the GameScene.  Depending on your game, you may not be able to use that.

Comment: My `func restart()` is in the `GameScene` class. How to I replace a view instead of creating a subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably defined this method inside your `GameScene` class, right?

Let's see what the API doc says about the `view` property of `SKScene`.

> The view that is currently presenting the scene. (read-only) To
>   present a scene, you call the presentScene: method or
>   presentScene:transition: method on the SKView class. If the scene is
>   not currently presented, this property holds **nil**.

So I guess you are calling this method after the current scene has been removed from the view.

### Is there a better way to reload the entire GameScene?

This approach is right, but you should call `restart` **before** the current scene has been removed from the view, otherwise it has no reference to your `view`.

### Do I need to do anything with the old discarded `GameScene` instance?

Nope.

Once you replace the current scene with the new one, if you don't have strong references to the old scene, ARC does remove it from memory.

To be sure the current scene is being removed you have several easy tools:

### 1. Debug Navigator

While the game is running take a look <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> at the `Debug Navigator` in Xcode, then invoke `restart` several times.
If the used memory indicator grows up, then probably you are not releasing the `GameScene` from memory (or some other object).

[image]

> Not releasing the GameScene is one of the worst thing that can happen in a videogame because a scene holds references (directly or indirectly) to every other node in you current level/screen. It happened during the development of my game so I know what I'm talking about :D

### 2. deinit

Add the `deinit` method to you `GameScene`

```
class GameScene : SKScene {
    deinit {
        print("The GameScene has been removed from memory")
    }
}
```

`deinit` is automatically called when the object is removed from memory. Now each time you restart your scene, you should see the message

*The GameScene has been removed from memory*

on the console coming from the *dead* scene.

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid but "you should call `restart` before the current scene has been removed from the view". I don't know how to do this. Currently, `restart` is called via a `NSNotificationCenter` observer when `appEnteredBackground`. How can I keep the reference to my `view`?

Comment: Ok tell me more about what you need to do. Why do you want to create a new `GameScene` when the app goes to background?

Comment: I want the game to be able to be played again from the beginning when the user next launches the app.

Comment: You can reset you app when it goes to background. Would it be acceptable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765355/restart-app-when-coming-out-of-background

Comment: Thank you - this fixed my problem.